# Convergence of sequence of functions $\frac{x^n}{n+x^{2n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have to study the convergence of this sequence of functions: $$\frac{x^n}{n+x^{2n}}$$

I find that the *pointwise convergence* is to $f(x)=0$ in all $\mathbb{R}$. How can I prove that also *converges uniformly* to $f(x)=0$ in all $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For each $n$, where do the minima and maxima of $f_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{n+x^{2n}}$ occur?

Comment: I got it. Thanks!